# Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rect should intersect with child's bounds

Tags: java, android

De vez en cuando obtengo el error en Android

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rect should intersect with child's
>    bounds

Es un error muy curioso, solo me pasa, cuando la app se instala por primera vez. He encontrado que es un [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222597) que afecta algunos terminales, es debido que uso la versión `new appcompat version to 24.2.1`.

Me pregunto si se puede ocultar el dialogo de error, porque si el usuario vuelve a pulsar sobre el icono de la app, se ejecuta bien.

Comment: Interesante, te sugiero cambiar a :24.2.0, yo no he actualizado a 24.2.1

Comment: La 24.X.X lleva un motón de bugs, la 24.2.1 soluciona el destello del fabbutton al realizar scroll arriba abajo rápidamente sin parar, a veces aparece abajo del todo un milisegundo y despues se ancla a donde debe estar.