# ¿Cómo modificar versión android.support en Gradle con Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Tengo un bug en mi aplicación que al parecer se resuelve usando una versión superior de Support.

¿Cómo cambiar la versión que uso?

He intentado editar mi fichero app/build.gradle, el cual cual contenía lo siguiente :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mi.aplicacion"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.3.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    // Unit testing dependencies
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
}
```

Y he cambiado la línea de `com.android.support:support-v4` a :

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'
```

Pero ahora la aplicación funciona peor que antes.

¿Es esta la forma correcta de cambiar de versión de Support? ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo desde la interfaz en vez de editando un fichero?

Comment: Cual es el bug? Lo digo porque la 24 da muchos problemas y porque usas la v4 teniendo la v7?

Comment: @Webserveis nunca usaste 24.2.0? si es así existe algún detalle que pudieras compartir?

Comment: @Elenasys la 24.2.0 solo detecte lo del fabutton que pierde el anchor si esta en cordinatorlayout, es cuando se hace scroll repetivamente, es decir con el dedo frenético arriba abajo. a veces aparece en la parte inferior. Lo probe con la plantilla que crea Android Studio, Activity Scroll

Comment: @Webserveis gracias por la information.

Comment: Otro bug que me encontrado es con Lollipop solo, que la snackbar no tiene animación, para solventarlo el usuario tiene que entrar a settings->preferencias de ascesibilidad activar y desactivar el selector. De todas la veces eso me ha pasado una vez y no puedo asegurar que versión usaba. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar la librería de soporte `24+`

El `targetSdkVersion` lo debes subir a 24  y con ello las `buildToolsVersion`

Te dejo mi gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.yourdomain.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    return true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
}
```

Pero actualmente la `24.2.1` tiene el [bug](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25684/error-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-rect-should-intersect-with-childs-bou) recomiendo quedarte con la `24.1.0`

Comment: Pues sí. Así me funciona, +1. Y he visto que ese fichero está en : Project -> Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle   .Con la ventaja de que el IDE se queja cuando cambias la versión de un elemento solo (como había hecho yo con un editor externo) sin cambiar el resto que hacen falta.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos aparte de eso en android studio el icono con tres cuadrados azules el tercero empezando por la derecha, en dependencias de la app, puedes gestionar todo graficamente